# how to automatically resume logging upon reboot of rem. host

Tags: linux, bash, logging, ssh, remote-access

I'm using a stcript like the below to display messages on a remote host I'm working on. Now, since it has to be rebooted regularly, I'd prefer the script to automatically attempt to reconnect as soon as it goes down. How can I do this?
Maybe have a ping going in the background as as soon as it experiences a hiccup (lost packet)  it would attempt to reconnect...?

Thanks for suggestions!

**my current script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1;
if [ $3 == "auto" ] ; then
    arg= sleep 1
else
    arg= read </dev/tty
fi

if [ -z ${2+x} ] ; then

    echo "blablabla";

elif [ $2 == "tail" ] ; then

    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 root@$1 tail -f /var/log/messages; echo "Reconnect?"; while $arg; do ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 root@$1 tail -f /var/log/messages; echo "Reconnect?"; done
```

Comment: `while true; do ssh ...; done`?

Comment: @Cyrus this is what it's doing already but the problem is that the ssh connection doesn't stop, i.e. isn't killed interrupted when the host reboots... (it boots up pretty quickly)